# Does this set the environmental variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to read through some source code and found this. Someone tell me what the second parameter "*29*" does?
I am used to only seeing one parameter

```
OWNER_ID = os.environ.get("OWNER_ID", "29")
```

Comment: It behaves sort of like how `dict.get()` does, the second argument is a default if the first argument isn't in the environment.

Comment: Ohh alright thanks alot

Comment: It sets the Python variable `OWNER_ID` to `"29"` if the environment variable `OWNER_ID` is *not* set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) returns a dedicated mapping type (and not a dictionary [as user2357112 has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833463/does-this-set-the-environmental-variable#comment123442569_69834190) in the comment) that inherits the `get()` method from the `Mapping` class, it works similarly to `dict.get()`. So the following line:

```py
OWNER_ID = os.environ.get("OWNER_ID", "29")
```

would be equivalent to

```py
try:
    OWNER_ID = os.environ["OWNER_ID"]
except KeyError:
    OWNER_ID = "29"
```

It implicitly handles the `KeyError` and returns the default value `"29"` instead of raising an error if the key `"OWNER_ID"` does not exist.

**See also:**

- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405/16936415)
- [Inspecting the original source code of os.environ](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/os.py#L768)

Comment: `os.environ` is not a dict. It's an instance of a dedicated mapping type, so it can write changes back to the actual environment when `os.environ` is mutated.

Comment: (Unfortunately, it won't reflect any changes that happen to the actual environment that *aren't* performed by mutating `os.environ`. This even includes [not showing the effect of calls to `os.putenv`](https://ideone.com/XzYSdp) - if you call `os.putenv` to set environment variables, Python provides no API to see the new values. Even `os.getenv` won't show them, because `os.getenv` looks at `os.environ` instead of the real environment.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ok, I see. I have taken a look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/os.py#L768) and it seems like `os.environ` is a variable that calls the `_createenviron()` function, which returns a class that inherits from `MutableMapping` and has a `get()` method. It is not a dict. Thank you for pointing out.